# Runtime, extension or tabs to send a message from background to content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been reading about message passing related to Chrome extension and native apps too.

After reading a lot of answers and docs, I saw some options to use when I want to send a message from background to content script.

Google docs says:

> Sending a request from the extension to a content script looks very
>   similar, except that you need to specify which tab to send it to. This
>   example demonstrates sending a message to the content script in the
>   selected tab.

However, I found some questions here on Stack Overflow using **runtime** and even **extension**.

In my case, I have an object from a native app in my background and I want to send it to my contentscript.

What is the best option here? **Tabs**, **runtime** or **extension**?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use case, `runtime` will not be useful. Reason from [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect):

> Note that this does not connect to any listeners in a content script. Extensions may connect to content scripts embedded in tabs via tabs.connect.

Also, all the methods of `chrome.extension` for message passing are deprecated ([Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension)).

So, the only possible way is to use [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification my friend! Appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help :)